# How to correct these normals along bevel?

Tags: normals, bevel

I imported a model and corrected the normals (from what I could tell) in solid display mode:
[image]

I hadn't noticed that the normals are still messed up all over this model until I used material display mode and now can see that along the bevels there are some tris that stick out even after I have set from faces.
[image]

I tried taking these faces and set normals from faces, I also tried smoothing them, flattening them,  averaging from face area, also merged all vertices in case that was causing it. I am not sure what else to try. Usually setting from face has worked.
[image]

Here is a view of the normals from the faces and some marked seams that were on the model when imported, the topology is likely an eye-sore, I am still working on cleaning it. For now I just want to learn why I cannot get these normals to match up, what am I missing?
Please let me know if further pictures are needed, and thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it was the material itself somehow causing it. I changed it to a basic material and none of the problems are showing.